# ESRI Javascript polygon

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I'm using ESRI JavaScript API 3.5. My polygon cannot load. Please help.

```
  dojo.require("esri.map");
  dojo.require("esri.graphic");

  var map;
  function init() {
    map = new esri.Map("map",{
      basemap:"topo",
      center:[103.8, 1.35], //long, lat
      zoom:13
    });
    dojo.connect(map, "onLoad", loadData);
  }//end init

  function loadData(){
     var arr = [];
     var p = new esri.geometry.Point(103.8, 1.35);
     arr.push(p);
     p = new esri.geometry.Point(103.8, 1.35222);
     arr.push(p);
     var polySymbolRed = new esri.symbol.SimpleFillSymbol(
       esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID,
       new esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol(esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID,
         new dojo.Color([0, 0, 0, 1]), 1),
       new dojo.Color([255, 0, 0, 0.2])
     );

     var gra = new esri.Graphic(arr,polySymbolRed);
     map.graphics.add(gra);
   }
```

Comment: Your polygon has fewer than 3 vertices, and is therefore not a polygon

Answer (score 3):

What you want to draw, isn't a polygon, it's a polyline! Like tomfumb already said, a polygon needs at least 3 vertices.

There are two solutions:
1. Add at least a 3 vertex, everything should work then.
2. Draw a polyline instead of the polygon:

```
dojo.require("esri.map");
dojo.require("esri.graphic");

  var map;
  function init() {
    map = new esri.Map("map",{
      basemap:"topo",
      center:[103.8, 1.35], //long, lat
      zoom:13
    });
    dojo.connect(map, "onLoad", loadData);
  }//end init

  function loadData(){

     var polyline = new esri.geometry.Polyline(new esri.SpatialReference({wkid:4326}));
     polyline.addPath([new esri.geometry.Point(103.8, 1.35), 
          new esri.geometry.Point(103.8, 1.35222);]);      

     var polylineSymbol = new esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol(
     esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID, 
     new dojo.Color([0,0,0]), 1);  

     var gra = new esri.Graphic(polyline, polylineSymbol);
     map.graphics.add(gra);
   }
```